# Is there any derivative that the TI-nspire can't do?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculator

A fellow student was showing off by having his TI-nspire calculator quickly solve homework problems.  Just wondering if there is any derivative that the TI-nspire would mess up on.

Comment: The problem is that differentiating most functions you'd think of is trivial. It could possibly be tricked with something like $\sum^\infty_{n=0}a^n \cos b^nx$ (it's nowhere differentiable). Honestly though, I have no clue how capable that system is.

Comment: I would try to play around on Wolfram Alpha. Chances are, if Wolfram Alpha can't do the derivative then neither can the calculator.

Comment: I would conjecture that there are infinitely many derivatives (which exist) which the calculator cannot do.

Comment: A related game is to find integrals that computer algebra systems should be able to do, but can't, because they don't understand what they're doing. One such example is $\int dx/(x^{10000}-1)$.

Comment: @Ben: Would you mind expanding your comment a bit?  I have no intuition for why a CAS "should" be able to do that integral, nor do I know what you mean by "they don't understand what they're doing."

Comment: @BenCrowell I agree with Jason DeVito, Could you briefly explain the abilities of a CAS, or provide a stable link?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: That particular integral was discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104528/int-dx-x10000-1

Comment: @ENDERMAN Please don't make purely cosmetic edits on old questions (particularly bad questions). That bumps them to the top of the active queue and wastes time for folks like me who follow that queue.